# Is there a difference between a shrub and a bush

Tags: discussion, tags

We have a [shrubs](https://gardening.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/shrubs) tag that is reasonably well used with 97 entries (44 this year), and we have a [bush](https://gardening.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/bush) tag with 5 questions this year and none before. Is there any noteworthy difference between a shrub and a bush? And if not, can we make bush a synonym for shrub.

Comment: I've wondered the same thing. I thought I remembered using [tag:bush] one time and it turned into [tag:shrubs], so I figured it was a synonym already.

Comment: No difference at all...it is like calling soil, dirt.  Bushes is NOT a professional term...shrub is correct.

Answer (score 4):

I agree J.Musser!  Shrub is the same as bush only more...professional...sort of like soil and dirt!  Soil is professional and dirt is dumb!  Grins

Answer (score 3):

I've removed [bush](https://gardening.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/bush) from the questions, it is unnecessary. It will disappear shortly.